# How do I delete an item in a CSV file?

Tags: powershell, csv

I have this powershell script which reads from a csv file and adds the new user to  AD. My problem is that i want to be able to delete the new user from the csv file that i have just added from the csv file. So the new user is not at the csv file enymore.

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

# Import list of Users From CSV into $Userlist
$userlist = Import-Csv "C:\employee.csv" 

# Step through Each Item in the List
foreach($person in $userlist){

    $givenName = $person.givenName
    Write-Output $givenName

    $Initials = $person.Initials
    Write-Output $Initials

    $mail = $person.mail
    Write-Output $mail

    $title = $person.title
    Write-Output $title

    $displayName = $person.displayName
    Write-Output $displayName

    $sn = $person.sn
    Write-Output $sn

    $telephoneNumber = $person.telephoneNumber
    Write-Output $telephoneNumber

    $manager = $person.manager
    Write-Output $manager

    #Adding the new user to AD
    New-ADUser $givenName -OtherAttributes @{givenName=$givenName;Initials=$Initials;mail=$mail;title=$title;displayName=$displayName;sn=$sn;telephoneNumber=$telephoneNumber;manager= 'CN='+$manager+',CN=Users,DC=jol,DC=local'}


    #Delete item in csv file after adding the new user.

}
```

Comment: I'm willing to guess the response from this but would the csv file not be completly processed and you could just remove the entire file? I don't see you checking if a user already exists so am I to assume that the csv contains all new users?

Comment: Yes, This file only contains all new users.

Comment: What would be the purpose of deleting the individual users then? At the end you would end up with an empty file correct?

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively if you wanted to remove them as they are created, you can do something like:

```
$ParsedCSV = $userlist
ForEach($Person in $UserList){
    Blah, blah, code and stuff to add users
    if($?){$ParsedCSV = $ParsedCSV | Where{$_ -ne $Person}
    $ParsedCSV | Export-CSV 'C:\employee.csv' -notype -force}
}
```

That removes the user from the list as it is made, and if the command to add the user works it removes that person from the $ParsedCSV array and outputs it to the CSV file overwriting the existing one. Considering the speed of AD I imagine the file writes and lock release should happen faster than account creation in most if not all cases.

Answer (score 0):

As @Matt already pointed out in the comments to the question: if you create all users listed in the file and remove each user from the file afterwards, your file would normally be empty after the loop completes, so you could just as well remove the file.

However, if you want to preserve records for which the account creation failed you could do something like this:

```
foreach($person in $userlist){
  ...
  New-ADUser $givenName -OtherAttributes @{...} -EA SilentlyContinue
  if (-not $?) { $person | Export-Csv "C:\employee.csv" -NoType -Append }
}
```

Note that `Export-Csv` doesn't support the `-Append` parameter prior to PowerShell v3. For earlier versions you need `... | ConvertTo-Csv -NoType | Out-File "C:\employee.csv" -Append` instead.

Comment: Don't you mean `if (!$?)` ?

Comment: @TheMadTechnician Indeed. Thanks for the heads up. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

How about creating a tmpfile if a user is not created correctly?  This would require error handling of some sort to catch users that were not created correctly.  I suggest wrapping the New-ADUser command with in a TRY / Catch.

```
#Before the foreach loop
out-file -FilePath "C:\tmpEmployee.csv"  -force

    #Inside the loop - add the new user to AD using TRY/Catch for error handling
    Try {
        New-ADUser $givenName -OtherAttributes @{givenName=$givenName;Initials=$Initials;mail=$mail;title=$title;displayName=$displayName;sn=$sn;telephoneNumber=$telephoneNumber;manager= 'CN='+$manager+',CN=Users,DC=jol,DC=local'}
    }
    Catch {[Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.NewADUser]
        #additional error handling code
        #export skipped user to tmpCSV File
    }

#After the foreach loop completes

#Rename files
Remove-Item -Path "C:\Employee.csv" -Force
Rename-Item "C:\tmpEmployee.csv" -NewName "C:\Employee.csv"

#
```